# "One to One" field not shown in the strapi

Tags: strapi

I created a collection named "Pictures" and I added two fields;
The first field titled as "desc" and the second one was a "realtion field" which links it to another table.
After creating a record, the "linking field" was not exists on response API.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass `?populate=item` in your api it will showing in result. any relational data or any media default not display. in strapi v4 you need to pass a populate as a query params for viewing the data